# Using jquery mobile and phonegap to write web application

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Anyone there has a guide how i can use phonegap with jquery mobile to build a web application for mobile web browser.(not native application) . something like http://coenraets.org/apps/directory/jqm/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[This website](http://css.dzone.com/articles/build-your-first-mobile-app) has a nice tutorial on how to integrate Phonegap and JQuery Mobile

Comment: thanks for link..but this gives me details for the native application ... i want to build a web application which will run on browser . can i use phonegap with jqm to get some feature of phonegap for my web app

Comment: Phone gap is for hybrid apps... it will be "like" a native app but you can develop UI in HTML & CSS and access mobile features through JS

Answer (score 0):

the question is not correct:
you want to make a webapplication and not a native one:
But phonegap does not create neither:
phonegap is solely for *hibrid* application,
web application who are confined in a local chromeless webview (*not* a full fledged browser), who can't directly access web (only via ajax call) *but* can access every hw\sw  device feature (that's the phonegap library role).
So, if you do not want the app to be or even look native and nonenthless you want it to run into the system browser,
you aren't really building a phonegap app but a webapp instead.
what you have to do is just write down your app using jquery mobile as a normal phone optimized web site, hosting it, ask user to point browser on it and you are done: that's a webapp.

Comment: ur answer justify the question ...that's what i was asking for ,  because i am new to jqm and phonegap !!